# What causes Unity Memory Leaks?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having memory leaks with Unity with the following code:

Behavior: in runtime, Unity eventually uses > 64GB of RAM and crashes (Thats all this machine has)

Scene: I only have one plane in my scene with the below code.

How do I fix this? I dont think I want a weak reference here, (or at least in C++ I wont use a weak_ptr in this scenario, maybe a unique_ptr). I just want the memory to be deallocated when objects fall out of scope.

```
void Start () {
    frameNumber_ = 0;

    // commented code leaks memory even if update() is empty
    //WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    //deviceName = devices[0].name;
    //wct = new WebCamTexture(deviceName, 1280, 720, 30);
    //GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = wct;
    //wct.Play();

    wct = new WebCamTexture(WebCamTexture.devices[0].name, 1280, 720, 30);
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = wct;
    wct.Play();
}

// Update is called once per frame
// This code in update() also leaks memory
void Update () {
    if (wct.didUpdateThisFrame == false)
        return;

    ++frameNumber_;

    Texture2D frame = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
    frame.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());
    frame.Apply();

    return;
```

Comment: I'm not good with unity, but I can already see something suspicious. You are creating new `Texture2D` every single frame. That is for sure going to pile up garbage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this:

```
Texture2D frame = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
```

You are crating new `Texture2D` almost every frame or when `didUpdateThisFrame`  is true. This is **very expensive** and most of the time is not even freed by Unity. You only need to create one `Texture2D` then re-use it in the `Update` function. Make the `frame` variable a global variable then initialize it **once** in the `Start` function.

---

By doing this, you will likely run into new problem when camera image height/width changes causing `frame.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());` to fail with an exception. To fix this, check when the camera texture size changes then automatically resize your `frame` Texture. This check should be done in the Update function before `frame.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());`.

```
if (frame.width != wct.width || frame.height != wct.height)
{
    frame.Resize(wct.width, wct.height);
}
```

Your final code should looks something like this:

```
int frameNumber_ = 0;
WebCamTexture wct;
Texture2D frame;

void Start()
{
    frameNumber_ = 0;

    wct = new WebCamTexture(WebCamTexture.devices[0].name, 1280, 720, 30);
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = wct;
    wct.Play();

    frame = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
}

// Update is called once per frame
// This code in update() also leaks memory
void Update()
{
    if (wct.didUpdateThisFrame == false)
        return;

    ++frameNumber_;

    //Check when camera texture size changes then resize your frame too
    if (frame.width != wct.width || frame.height != wct.height)
    {
        frame.Resize(wct.width, wct.height);
    }

    frame.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());
    frame.Apply();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, however, I do find it quite strange that unity does not free the texture when it falls out of scope. Isnt the point of a managed language not to have to worry about memory allocation costs? (In C++ you could use a custom memory allocator like a memory pool with a std::vector<> and allocating memory becomes very cheap)

Comment: This is a Texture not just a simple object. It's very expensive for Unity to create and free textures. You are responsible for doing both. I think that the  `Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets()` and `DestroyImmediate` should help free the Texture. If Unity is doing this for you, the game could be so slow or freezing once in a while due to hiccups from GC. It's better to leave that to the programmer. If they hadn't done that, you wouldn't know that it's a bad idea to create new texture every frame but when you are done making your game, you'll realize that it's impossible to play on mobile devices.

Comment: @aCuria Managed languages automatically free up managed resources *only.* Un-managed resources (such as this texture, or a web socket, etc) exist for a number of reasons, including backwards compatibility with un-managed code, such as C++ DirectX libraries. The CLR can't effectively manage these resources, and therefore the decision to free up the memory is left up to the developer - who is required to understand when it is appropriate to do so. .NET provides the `IDisposable` interface to denote such resources, but Unity has not implemented that interface for this class.

Comment: How would you know if an object is managed or not? C# does not seem to indicate this - you use "new" on all non-POD types, so its not clear for what objects you are responsible for the lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

Archaic topic but I found something interesting. I used to have this in my code:

```
            downloadedTexture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
        m_PictureScreen.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = downloadedTexture;
```

this caused huge problems with memory leaks, app went over 8gb with every iteration of that. I my case that could ramp up to thousands of files per day.
I solved it by using this line before:

```
Texture2D.Destroy(m_PictureScreen.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture);
```

Not sure how but it worked and memory leaks do not exist now.